# Whitespace required. XMLParseException?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm trying to work with some xml that I must read, some of them work, some others don't. The XML is well formed, I checked it, but I just don't know where do this White Space should go, or if it's something different.
The console errror im having is :

> The  following stacktrace is related to an error identified as: 0ac50429-bf9e-39ff-81bf-9e5cc511882b 
>   Whitespace required.
>   oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException: Whitespace required.
>       at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrors(XMLError.java:148)
>       at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseAttrValue(NonValidatingParser.java:1387)
>       at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseAttr(NonValidatingParser.java:1292)
>       at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseAttributes(NonValidatingParser.java:1234)
>       at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseElement(NonValidatingParser.java:1088)
>       at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseRootElement(NonValidatingParser.java:293)
>       at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:260)

Thanks!

Comment: add an example of xml that is not working

Comment: Solved! The isse was in the xml, it had some strange quotes,  so the parser read them as the end of the node instead of text. I deteled them, added myself and problem solved.
A hint to see where the issue was, is to put a catch in the exception, and check for this properties : numLIne and columLine, they give you a near place where the issue is.